# How do I specify which FlaggedRevs marker corresponds to the stable version of a page

Tags: configuration, mediawiki

I'm trying to configure the [FlaggedRevs](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aFlaggedRevs) extension to a Wiki based on [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/) (currently V1.19.1). I've read the documentation closely several times, but I can't quite achieve what I want.

My objective is to display the stable version of pages to users. Any edits must be reviewed against a single scale with four flags. Only once a page is reviewed to the top flag of the scale should the current version become the stable version.

What I've done so far: I've configured my own scale called *content* and its component flags; and I've configured users, editors and reviewers. The key scale configuration code is:

```
$wgFlaggedRevsTags = array(
    'content' => array( 'levels' => 3, 'quality' => 2, 'pristine' => 3 ),
);
```

My results: When I edit a page those edits are viewed as pending. Users see the stable version of the page. All good so far. However, once I review the page and upgrade the scale from the lowest flag (0) to the next flag (1), the current version becomes the stable version. This is not what I want; upgrading to stable should require the top flag (3), not any flag but the least (0).

How do I configure FlaggedRevs such the *stable* version of a page corresponds to the *pristine* marker?

Edited to add: my experience and jpatokal's answer seem to differ. Does 'levels' => 3 give me flags(0,1,2) or (0,1,2,3). I get the latter, but is the extension adding a 0=Unreviewed flag for me or am I specifying it? How do the *quality* and *pristine* settings work too?

Comment: I wrote my answer without checking our live config and was completely wrong, so I've deleted it.  Levels=3 does give you three levels, and while I thought I understood how stable/pristine/quality work, I apparently don't (since in our system even level 1 is stable).  Sorry for wasting your time =/

Comment: No problem. We're all here to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reach one of the extension authors via their Mediawiki talk page. Turns out the extension documentation is a little out of date. Here's the latest:

> The flags determine whether a revision is checked/quality/pristine. These tiers can be queried at UnreviewedPages and PendingChanges (the special pages) to keep the quality/pristine versions up to date. By they are updated "asynchronously". That is newer "checked" versions "go live" before it gets marked as "quality" or better. This reduces the average time for people's edits to get through and simplifies the UI.

So my observation matches the currently intended operation. The visible (stable) version depends on the *checked* marker, The *quality* and *pristine* markers are kind of independent to this (but still have value in improving quality).

So the answer to my question, is perhaps there is no answer. That is, what I was after cannot be achieved directly as it's not the intention of the extension.